# Laravel app works well as localhost:8000 and not as lms.app

Tags: laravel

I have developed a laravel application. However when I after making a successful authentication with php artisan. The login runs into this problem

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = paulson@gmail.com limit 1)

only when I use lms.app. When I run the same project as localhost:8000 everything works well. I have done much codding. I have just started with the test for authentication

This is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:lGuAkp+tlvCJriluZA+KdgWlspUG24Q6OEMLXHGwj6M=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel_lms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

And this is my database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel_lms'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

This is my yaml file

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\George\Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:

    - map: lms.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/lms/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And this is my host file

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

192.168.10.10 lms.app
```

What could be the problem. I would prefer to run this app and do everything as lms.app

Comment: did you successfully set up vagrant / homestead ? You database is probably saved locally, you can call yourappname.app if you set up vagrant / homestead, there you also set up a database which is not locally (its on a ubunutu machine)

Comment: You should probably go through this first [docs homestead doc laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)  and have a look at some videos which explain that aswell.

Comment: Yes my database is locally..on xampp mysql

Comment: I have done that..its working well as lms.app, aslo but it doesn't save or call login credentials here .But when I run it on localhost:8000 it runs well and even registers and logs in

Answer (score 0):

Ok you probably did not set up your database in your homestead machine.

First connect to your machine with this command:

```
vagrant ssh
```

or this one

```
homestead shh
```

After that you connect to your database like this (-u is your username and -p your password):

```
mysql -u homestead -p
```

After that you can run your sql commands / migrations to create the database and tables.

To create the database run this for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_app_name;
```

Follow these steps and tell me what happened I will update my answer afterwards.

Comment: Its not allowing me , yet I have no password for it

Comment: Your username is root and the password is empty same as those in your. Env file